# Import data into SQL Server 2012 using wizard lost data (have date and empty cells in the same column)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is not a new issue and I have browsed a lot but could not figure it out.

The table contains a column with a few dates (like 25-Apr-16) while the majority of the rows are empty. After importing to SQL, there is only NULL left; all the dates were gone.

I have tried three methods:

1. save the file to .xls, change the column to Date format;
2. save the file to .xls, fill up empty with NULL, change the column to Date format;
3. save to .csv;

So far, none of them worked.

At last, I tried this and it worked, but I am wondering if there are better ways:

4. save the file to .xls, fill up empty with 12/31/9999, after importing, update 12/31/9999 to NULL.

Comment: sounds like a question for [dba.se]

Comment: What is the source for this table, MSSQL, MYSQL, etc?

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL server 2012 Management Studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue when you import data to SQL Server is that SQL Server try to wonder what kind of data is in each cell of the sheet, and it does their research on the first 100 records. So if there is anything on the top 100 records of a cell, SQL Server considers that the cell is empty. To avoid that, you can fill the first record of your Excel sheet with dummy values and after that  import to SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks.